# Java Pattern & Matcher - Not able to extract pattern if starting character is a \"

Tags: java

I am trying to extract a URL from a String:
`"http://cdn.posh24.com/images/:profile/0a749b802defbf357e7ccf1361ccabef5" alt="Rita Ora"`

I have created the following method to do so. My intention is for the pattern to be everything within the first `\"` to the second `\"`, Thus I would extract just the URL in the above string. However I always get a '**No successful match so far**' error.

```
public String extractImagePattern(String string) {
    String localImageResult = "";
    try {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\" alt");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
        localImageResult = m.group(1);

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return localImageResult;

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why the `?` after the `.*`?

Comment: You need to call `find()` on your matcher before you call `group()`

Comment: @khelwood - Thanks! I am a huge idiot for forgetting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making your matcher, you need to call [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) (so it will actually try and make a match) before calling [`group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)) to get the group from the match it found.

From the docs for `find()`:

> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and **group** methods.